# Is it possible to create an updater that downloads files from a web server using NSIS?

Tags: nsis, auto-update

I have created a mini installer in NSIS that installs patches for my application. I want to create an NSIS software updater that would download this mini installer from the web server. Is it possible?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the [NSISdl](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSISdl_plug-in) plug-in.

Comment: Great! thanks...

Now, given that I'm able to download the mini installer from the web server, is there also a way for the local installer to check for the latest mini installer available from the web server. I've heard you can do that through a web service. But is it possible with NSIS too?

Thanks...